# Removing trash information from an exploded string

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working with an API that sends me a string of information, separated by an undefined number of spaces. When I try exploding it, I end up with some elements composed solely of spaces. I've tried using a `foreach`, `preg_replace`, `preg_match`, pretty much everything I could find to get rid of these spaces, but there are still some left, The strange thing is, even if I replace these spaces with another symbol and then explode the string and remove the elements composed only of this symbol, the space-only elements remain. Also, any method of removing them removes some, but there's usually 2 or 3 that remain between each array position that contains useful information.

Example: I recieve a string that looks something like this (I'm using // to separate elements):

> // // // // // // // // // //1000 // // // // // // // // // // // //0
>   // // // // // // // //1 // // // // // // // //1 // // // //101 // //
>   // // // // // //272 // // // // // // // //ubuntu-10.04-x86 // // //
>   //basic // // // // // // // //true // // // //running // // // //0 //
>   // // // // // // // // // // //1000 // // // // // // // // // // //
>   //0 // // // // // // // //1 // // // // // // // //2 // // // //102
>   // // // // // // // //272 // // // // // // // //ubuntu-10.04-x86 //
>   // // //basic // // // // // // // //true // // // //running // // //
>   //0 // // // // // // // // // // // //1000 // // // // // // // // //
>   // // //0 // // // // // // // //1 // // // // // // // //3 // // //
>   //103 // // // // // // // //0 // // // // // // // //ubuntu-10.04-x86
>   // // // //vswap-256m // // // // // // // //false // // // //stopped
>   // // // // // // //

When I do

```
$result  = preg_replace('/\s[\s]+/', '-', $result);
$result = preg_split('~-~', $result, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

foreach($result as $item){
    echo "$item //";
}
```

for example, I end up with this:

> // // //1000 // // //0 // //1 // //1 //101 // //272 // //ubuntu
>   //10.04 //x86 //basic // //true //running //0 // // // //1000 // //
>   //0 // //1 // //2 //102 // //272 // //ubuntu //10.04 //x86 //basic //
>   //true //running //0 // // // //1000 // // //0 // //1 // //3 //103 //
>   //0 // //ubuntu //10.04 //x86 //vswap //256m // //false //stopped //
>   // //

Anyone know how I can get rid of those empty elements from the array?

Comment: Can you modify the API ? this is a mess !

Comment: I can't. I think it's pretty messy too, but such is life, I guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) to filter out elements according to your own criteria.

```
$result = array_filter($result,
                       function($e) { return trim($e) != ''; });
```

Comment: I'm getting a version problem. I this php5.3?

Comment: Yes, anonymous functions is in PHP since 5.3. It should work just as well in 5.4. For older versions of PHP (which nobody should use since security bugs are not fixed anymore) you must create a regular function and pass to array_filter instead.

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something here, but can't you just:

```
$array = preg_split('/\s\s+/', $input, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

?

[Like this](http://codepad.org/vHDXjtHx)

Comment: Just `\s+` (instead of `\s\s+`) should do, if data is really separated only by whitespace.

Comment: @raina77ow The `\s\s+` will account for the fact that data may contain a single whitespace character. Although if it won't ever contain one, then you are correct.

Comment: Well, it'd be really weird to use whitespace as a separator for the data that may contain whitespaces - and has no other means (like double quote signs, for example) of marking the data. ) But I see your point.

Comment: @raina77ow Indeed, but obviously this is a stupidly designed API in first place, without seeing the spec it's impossible to know whether that would be an issue or not. Assuming the spec is "two or more whitespace characters", `/\s\s+/` is appropriate. If it is "one or more whitespace characters" then simply `/\s+/` is the answer.

Comment: @Mariana Does your input data look like it does in the example I linked?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the empty elements first :

```
$str = preg_replace('%//\s+%', '', $str);
```

This removes the `//<space>` from the string

[example here](http://codepad.org/OhWtzMw2)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$match = array();
preg_match_all ( '/[^\s]+/' , $result, $matches);
print_r($match);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Where $str is the crazy string.    
$fixed = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $str);
$result = preg_split('~//~', $fixed, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_export($result);
```